# Changing the radius of a point light

Tags: light

When creating a point light, there is a "radius" value in the properties panel.  This works perfectly.  However, I can't find any way to change this afterwards, in the properties panel or search bar.

https://youtu.be/oRRpTdY5g0U

In this video, I create a couple of lights with different radiuses and test that they work as expected, but cannot see a way to change those radiuses.  Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the falloff distance in the point light properties. A radius of 1 create a fallout distance of 25 and it is directly proportional to that. So a radius of 2 has a fallout distance of 50.

[image]